# VirtualBox: NS_ERROR_FAILURE error on MacOS Sierra

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox, macos-sierra

I am using virtualbox+vagrant for running a virtual machine for development purposes. It was running perfectly fine before I made the stupid mistake of upgrading to Sierra. Here's the trace:

```
nkohlis-MacBook-Pro:vagrant nkohli$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["hostonlyif", "create"]

Stderr: 0%...
Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: 

failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterface, interface IHostNetworkInterface
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleCreate(HandlerArg*, int, int*)" at line 66 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
```

I tried one of the solutions suggested elsewhere:

```
nkohlis-MacBook-Pro:vagrant nkohli$ sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh restart
Password:
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxAutostart => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxAutostart-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxBalloonCtrl => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxBalloonCtrl-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxDD2GC.gc => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxDD2GC.gc-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxDDGC.gc => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxDDGC.gc-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxExtPackHelperApp => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxExtPackHelperApp-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxHeadless => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxHeadless-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxManage-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxNetAdpCtl => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxNetAdpCtl-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxNetDHCP => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxNetDHCP-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxNetNAT => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxNetNAT-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxSVC => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxSVC-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxXPCOMIPCD => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VBoxXPCOMIPCD-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VMMGC.gc => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VMMGC.gc-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBox => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBox-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBoxVM => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/VirtualBoxVM-amd64
/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/vboxwebsrv => /Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/vboxwebsrv-amd64
Loading VBoxDrv.kext
/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
Error: Failed to load /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxDrv.kext
Loading VBoxUSB.kext
/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxUSB.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
Error: Failed to load /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxUSB.kext
Loading VBoxNetFlt.kext
/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetFlt.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
Error: Failed to load /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetFlt.kext
Loading VBoxNetAdp.kext
/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetAdp.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) not loadable (reason unspecified); check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
Error: Failed to load /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/VBoxNetAdp.kext
(kernel) Kext org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp not found for unload request.
Failed to unload org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp - (libkern/kext) not found.
(kernel) Kext org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt not found for unload request.
Failed to unload org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt - (libkern/kext) not found.
(kernel) Kext org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB not found for unload request.
Failed to unload org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB - (libkern/kext) not found.
(kernel) Kext org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv not found for unload request.
Failed to unload org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv - (libkern/kext) not found.
Fatal error: VirtualBox
```

...to no avail.

Here's the stack trace when I ran `vagrant up` after reinstalling VirtualBox:

```
failed MSpanList_Insert 0x1e3000 0x215290116bd5 0x0
fatal error: MSpanList_Insert

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x19816b)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/panic.go:491 +0xad fp=0x7fff5fbff7d0 sp=0x7fff5fbff7a0
runtime.MSpanList_Insert(0x1b3988, 0x1e3000)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:692 +0x8f fp=0x7fff5fbff7f8 sp=0x7fff5fbff7d0
MHeap_FreeSpanLocked(0x1b0580, 0x1e3000, 0x100)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:583 +0x163 fp=0x7fff5fbff838 sp=0x7fff5fbff7f8
MHeap_Grow(0x1b0580, 0x8, 0x0)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:420 +0x1a8 fp=0x7fff5fbff878 sp=0x7fff5fbff838
MHeap_AllocSpanLocked(0x1b0580, 0x1, 0x0)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:298 +0x365 fp=0x7fff5fbff8b8 sp=0x7fff5fbff878
mheap_alloc(0x1b0580, 0x1, 0x12, 0x0)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:190 +0x121 fp=0x7fff5fbff8e0 sp=0x7fff5fbff8b8
runtime.MHeap_Alloc(0x1b0580, 0x1, 0x10000000012, 0x10d39)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mheap.c:240 +0x66 fp=0x7fff5fbff918 sp=0x7fff5fbff8e0
MCentral_Grow(0x1b82f8, 0x0)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mcentral.c:197 +0x8b fp=0x7fff5fbff980 sp=0x7fff5fbff918
runtime.MCentral_CacheSpan(0x1b82f8, 0x0)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mcentral.c:85 +0x167 fp=0x7fff5fbff9b8 sp=0x7fff5fbff980
runtime.MCache_Refill(0x1df000, 0x12, 0x0)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/mcache.c:90 +0xa0 fp=0x7fff5fbff9e0 sp=0x7fff5fbff9b8
runtime.mcacheRefill_m()
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/malloc.c:368 +0x57 fp=0x7fff5fbffa00 sp=0x7fff5fbff9e0
runtime.onM(0x13d650)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:273 +0x9a fp=0x7fff5fbffa08 sp=0x7fff5fbffa00
runtime.mallocgc(0x120, 0xff4a0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:178 +0x849 fp=0x7fff5fbffab8 sp=0x7fff5fbffa08
runtime.newobject(0xff4a0, 0x1df000)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:353 +0x49 fp=0x7fff5fbffae0 sp=0x7fff5fbffab8
runtime.newG(0x2520a)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/proc.go:233 +0x2a fp=0x7fff5fbffaf8 sp=0x7fff5fbffae0
allocg(0x1a33e0)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/proc.c:925 +0x1f fp=0x7fff5fbffb08 sp=0x7fff5fbffaf8
runtime.malg(0x8000, 0x1a3480)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/proc.c:2106 +0x1f fp=0x7fff5fbffb38 sp=0x7fff5fbffb08
runtime.mpreinit(0x1a3840)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/os_darwin.c:137 +0x27 fp=0x7fff5fbffb50 sp=0x7fff5fbffb38
mcommoninit(0x1a3840)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/proc.c:201 +0xc9 fp=0x7fff5fbffb78 sp=0x7fff5fbffb50
runtime.schedinit()
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/proc.c:138 +0x55 fp=0x7fff5fbffba0 sp=0x7fff5fbffb78
runtime.rt0_go(0x7fff5fbffbd8, 0x2, 0x7fff5fbffbd8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x7fff5fbffcd0, 0x7fff5fbffcd8, 0x0, 0x7fff5fbffcdb, ...)
    /Users/mitchellh/code/3rdparty/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:95 +0x116 fp=0x7fff5fbffba8 sp=0x7fff5fbffba0
```

I've looked around but didn't find a similar issue reported elsewhere.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Upgrading Vagrant and VirtualBox fixed the issue for me. For those wondering, no you don't end up losing your existing VMs if you upgrade.

- Vagrant: https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html
- VirtualBox: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: That was the strangest bug fix. I was getting the same error and installing the latest version of VirtualBox fixed it. I wonder if we can link this issue to a particular bug in VirtualBox?

Comment: I fixed it by installing only Vagrant.

Answer (score 4):

some [reported](https://twitter.com/aaronpinero/status/778657920321978368) issues after update to macos Sierra. re-installing Virtualbox solves the issue

Comment: I tried this and got an entirely different trace, pasted above. Thanks.

Comment: weird, it looks like a go error, why would it put go error in there ?! I don't know ... will wait a bit still before I migrate to Sierra

Comment: Re-installing VirtualBox worked for me on Sierra, VirtualBox version "5.0.26" to work with Vagrant version "1.7.4"

Answer (score 4):

This issue affects anyone installing VirtualBox for the first time on a fresh macOS High Sierra 10.13.

This effectively breaks our fully automated installation process on macOS, since the user now has to perform a manual approval and then restart the installation (reboot and rerun the installation in some cases)

First, try to restart the Virtualbox with below command.

```
sudo "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox/LaunchDaemons/VirtualBoxStartup.sh" restart
```

If you are still facing this issue then given assign the below permission as per the screenshot.
[image]

Note: If the Allow button does not show up, run `sudo kextcache -system-caches`

Source: https://github.com/docksal/docksal/issues/417

Comment: This was the correct answer for me also !

Answer (score 1):

Solved. VirtualBox would always fail installation no matter how many times I tried. What worked for me was to reboot and try again, it worked! (Earlier, before trying to install, I had already upgraded fuse, vagrant, and checked to 'allow' Oracle to load its extensions from the System Preferences/Security panel. The key thing was the computer reboot before trying to install VB on High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command in your terminal:

```
for bin in VirtualBox VirtualBoxVM VBoxNetAdpCtl VBoxNetDHCP VBoxNetNAT VBoxHeadless; do
    sudo chmod u+s "/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/MacOS/${bin}"
done
```

It worked for me without upgrading anything.

NOTE: This will allow any user on your system to run any of these commands as root. Please be sure you understand what these commands mean before you run them.